# Suspend all actions on app launch/init until get ajax response

Tags: ajax, initialization, extjs6

I'm trying to find a way to stop any actions until the Ajax request will return any data. Request is calling in Application init() method.

Example:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    ...
    init: function() {
        // SUSPEND APP LOADING
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            ...
            success: function() { 
                // CONTINUE app loading 
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Just i have to prevent any actions of controllers in App until first request will return any answer.
suspendEvents is not a way... or I use it wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `async:false` ajax option, to wait till ajax request get completed

**Try this:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    ...
    init: function() {
        // SUSPEND APP LOADING
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            ...
            async: false,
            success: function() { 
                // CONTINUE app loading 
            }
        })
    }
});
```

It will prevent further code, till ajax request complete